# GROUP BY with SUM and Latest Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
 TableA.MaterialCode, 
 TableB.LotNumber, 
 SUM(TableB.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
 CONVERT(varchar(25), TableC.IssueDate, 121) AS IssueDate
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN
 TableB ON TableA.PONumber = TableB.PONumber 
INNER JOIN
 TableC ON TableA.PONumber = TableC.PONumber
WHERE TableC.VendorID = 'VendorID'
AND TableC.IssueDate > '10/25/2016  9:47:53 AM'
GROUP BY MaterialCode, LotNumber, IssueDate
ORDER BY TableC.IssueDate DESC
```

Which returns a dataset like so:

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ MaterialCode ║ LotNumber ║ Quantity ║        IssueDate        ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║        12345 ║   3451972 ║       55 ║ 2016-10-25 10:48:13.210 ║
║        12346 ║   3436055 ║       32 ║ 2016-10-25 09:57:26.693 ║
║        12346 ║   3436055 ║      224 ║ 2016-10-25 09:47:54.077 ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

I would like to expand on this to instead of grouping by the IssueDate, to just get the latest date in the group. I have tried the code below, but it throws the error `...because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

```
SELECT 
 TableA.MaterialCode, 
 TableB.LotNumber,
 SUM(TableB.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
 MAX(CONVERT(varchar(25), TableC.IssueDate, 121)) AS IssueDate
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN
 TableB ON TableA.PONumber = TableB.PONumber 
INNER JOIN
 TableC ON TableA.PONumber = TableC.PONumber
WHERE TableC.VendorID = 'VendorID'
AND TableC.IssueDate > '10/25/2016  9:47:53 AM'
GROUP BY MaterialCode, LotNumber
ORDER BY TableC.IssueDate DESC
```

Here is the output I was hoping to get with above query:

```
╔══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ MaterialCode ║ LotNumber ║ Quantity ║        IssueDate        ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║        12345 ║   3451972 ║       55 ║ 2016-10-25 10:48:13.210 ║
║        12346 ║   3436055 ║      256 ║ 2016-10-25 09:57:26.693 ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

How can I alter my query to achieve the above dataset?

Comment: In both queries you select `TableA.PONumber` but it isn't in the result set, nor is it in the `group by`. I would have expected both queries to fail.

Comment: Additionally, you should use the `max` on the `date` column, and do the convert to `varchar` later. A `max` on `varchar` values can (and usually do) lead to unexpected results.

Comment: So: should `TableA.PONumber` be included in the query and output, or excluded?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Sorry, that was a copy and paste error, updating the post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT 
     a.MaterialCode, 
     b.LotNumber, 
     SUM(b.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
     CONVERT(varchar(25), MAX(c.IssueDate), 121) AS MaxIssueDate
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN
    TableB b ON a.PONumber = b.PONumber 
INNER JOIN
    TableC c ON a.PONumber = c.PONumber
WHERE c.VendorID = 'VendorID'
    AND c.IssueDate > '10/25/2016  9:47:53 AM'
GROUP BY a.MaterialCode, b.LotNumber
ORDER BY MaxIssueDate DESC;
```

And as comment above, if you want to include `a.PONumber` in result set, then add it in `GROUP BY` clause too.

The SELECT `MAX(CONVERT(varchar(25), TableC.IssueDate, 121)) AS IssueDate` is not an issue, the problem here is your `ORDER BY` clause.

You could use `ORDER BY MAX(CONVERT(varchar(25), TableC.IssueDate, 121))`, but it's better to use just `ORDER BY MaxIssueDate` like above code.